# Symfony3 QueryBuilder orderBy entity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm building a query as an EntityRepository  with querybuilder. I have a ManyToOne relationship (by the ID) im trying to order the query by a value of the relationship instead. Code snippets below.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Repository;
class ContratoRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getWithoutParams($ops)
    {

        $query=$this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->orderBy('e.proc','ASC');
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Now my entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\ContratoRepository")
 */

    class Contrato
    {
...
     /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ContratosAdmin\Proc")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_proc", referencedColumnName="id_proc")
         * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
         **/
        private $proc;
```

Now my question is, is it possible to order by the "name" field inside my Proc Entity ? as it is now, it's ordering by it's Id.

Thank you,
Regards.

Comment: Try to make a `join` request in the `ContratoRepository` to retrieve the data of `Contrato` AND `Proc` entity. then in your queryBuilder request you will have something like `->orderBy('p.name','ASC');` where `p` represent your `Proc` entity.

Comment: thank you Grechka fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible according to the doctrine documentation:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

But according to this you'll have to adjust your query a bit otherwise the orderBy Annotation won't be included in the query.

Try this query:

```
public function getWithoutParams($ops)
    {
        $query=$this->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->select('e, p')
               ->leftJoin('e.proc', 'p');

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

According to the docs the orderBy should be added automatically in this case.

For a use without the Annotation just join the relation and add a manual orderBy like Grechka mentioned.

Comment: Nice, never knew that there are ordering annotations :)